# Paypal REST API: Which credentials to use to approve payments in sandbox mode?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to integrate paypal payments with my application using the Node.js SDK. In the sandbox mode, I can create the payment which gives me all the details about the payment, including the `approval_url` where I redirect the user. On that page, I can either cancel the payment by clicking the cancel button. This flow works fine and I am redirected to the `cancel_url` that I provide while creating the payment. However, I want to test the flow for approving the payment. However, my login credentials do not work in this case. It gives the error:

> Check your email address and password and try again.

I could not find in the documentation which credentials to use to test the process end to end in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing in the sandbox you need to create a sandbox seller account (which it sounds like you've already done) and you'll need to create a sandbox buyer account.  Basically, two separate sandbox accounts.

The credentials you use in your app would be from your seller (receiver), and the login credentials you would use for testing an actual payment is from the sandbox buyer account (sender).